# Is it possible to see a member variable's hard-coded value using a disassembler like Reflector?

Tags: .net, reflector, disassembly

Given the example source code below, is it possible for someone to see the value of `_secret` using a disassembler?  I didn't see a way to get at the value via Reflector, but I haven't used it very much.  Assume the code is not obfuscated in any way.

```
class Foo
{
    private string _secret = @"all your base are belong to us";

    public void Foo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's visible in the constructor in Reflector.

```
class Foo { private string _secret = @"all your base are belong to us"; }
```

translates to having constructor

```
public Foo() { this._secret = "all your base are belong to us"; }
```

which is visible in Reflector under `Foo` in method `.ctor`.

You can also see this information in `ildasm` (ships with Microsoft Visual Studio) in `Foo::.ctor : void`:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed {
    // Code size       19 (0x13)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "all your base are belong to us"
    IL_0006:  stfld      string Playground.Foo::_secret
    IL_000b:  ldarg.0
    IL_000c:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Foo::.ctor
```

Finally, if someone knows the name of your type and the name of your private field, you can obtain the value as such:

```
object o = typeof(Foo).GetField(
    "_secret",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
).GetValue(f);
Console.WriteLine(o); // writes "all your base are belong to us" to the console
```

Of course, I can always see all of your private fields with

```
var fields = typeof(Foo).GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
);
```

Comment: I figured it was in there, but I couldn't find it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  The hard-coded value will be present in the IL and will be viewable via any .NET disassembler.  Since this is a field, its initialization from the literal will be viewable in the constructor in Reflector.